# extract number from alphanumeric string

Tags: java

I want to extract string '265.12' or '0.00' from an alphanumeric string which can have either value '265.12+' or '265.12-' and '0.0+' or '0.0-' in java.

Is it possible to replace in one go instead of using two replace methods for + and - sign ?

Comment: You didn't even motivate the use of a replace method. You can use the substring method inside a condition that checks the last character. The condition can be done as a switch statement.

Comment: The input and output is not clear, can you give a full example of what a string will be like and what you want to extract?

Comment: Do you want to keep the number or everything but the number?

Comment: Input string = '$ 256.12 +' or '$ 256.12 -'
Output string = '256.12'

Answer (score 0):

I think `.replaceAll("\\$ ?(.+) ?[+-]", "$1")` should do the trick.

PS: corrected by @MarkoTopolnik :)

PS: recorrected by @userUnknown --'

PS: reedited by myself =D

Comment: Why not "[+\\-]"? Way simpler.

Comment: You don't need to mask the minus in a group, if it is the last or first character of that group. `[+-]` or `[-+]` is fine.

Comment: @userunknown Great tip! I'll use it myself one of these days :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: As repetition makes no sense in `[...]`-groups, the wildchar `.` doesn't, so they don't need masking either, btw. Similar, you have to define a start and end for a range like `[0-9]`. You could argue, that `[-z]` shall mean `from Character.toChar (0) to ...`, but when would somebody use it? How far would `[a-]` reach? 127, 255, max-short, max-int, max-UTF?

Comment: @sp00m: You improved your regex, but the question was to replace numbers and sign in one go - while I'm still uncertain: Does user13... want to replace number and sign or everything except them?

Comment: @userunknown It could be one of those askers... asks a half-baked question and then disappears. Strange behavior, but I see a lot of it around here.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yes, and most of them share similar names, 'user13...'.

Comment: @userunknown But nevermind, we had a nice chat and I learned a good regex tip!

Comment: i want Input string = '$ 256.12 +' or '$ 256.12 -' Output string = '256.12'

Answer (score 0):

An efficient implementation for your specific use case:

```
String extractNum(String in) {
  final char last = in.charAt(in.length()-1);
  return (last == '+' || last == '-') ? in.substring(0, in.length()-1) : in;
}
```

Comment: It is not sure sign will be present in last, above method may remove some other data